# Should websites display an accessibility toolbar if they already comply with WCAG AA?

Tags: accessibility

When a website has been properly designed to comply with WCAG AA, is it really useful to also provide an accessibility toolbar for bigger text, high contrast, dyslexic font etc?

Because most of these features can be managed by the OS or browser settings/extensions. I'm thinking that users who really need them may already have them set up.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is still useful, provided it is well designed.

Someone could be viewing your site in a library and not on their own computer so the font size isn't big enough.

Or maybe they are in a real bright environment and struggling to see on their phone, high contrast could be useful temporarily.

The scenarios are endless where this becomes useful.

But I think the key thing that we as developers tend to forget is that **a lot of people are not computer literate.**

Just because **you** know how to enable high contrast mode or increase the font size, doesn't mean everyone does.

As accessibility is all about making sites as easy to use as possible, for as many people as possible, I would say that a toolbar to adjust settings on the sites is a great idea!

Just make sure you test it well and that it doesn't interfere with assistive tech (or is easy to disable).